# Scikit train test issue for neural network

Tags: scikit-learn

I am trying to train a neural network model for the iris data.The code does fine when I split the training and test data into 50%, but when the data is into 60% for traning and 40% for test I get an error.This is my code

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.4,random_state=1)

clf = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5,hidden_layer_sizes=(15,), random_state=1)


 clf.fit(X_train, y_train)  
    y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)  
    print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_train,y_pred))
```

this is the error

```
print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_train,y_pred))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-51-aacc5d70d13b>", line 1, in <module>
    print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_train,y_pred))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 172, in accuracy_score
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 72, in _check_targets
    check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 181, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [90, 60]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare `y_test` and `y_pred` if `y_pred` is predicted using `X_test`:

```
print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))
```

The `accuracy_score` will check how much of the two given arrays matches. This is only possible if they have the same shape. You will also have quite a random behaviour if you compare the predicted labels using the test set with the true values of the training set, since they do not correspond to each other.